# How to generate NON-transparent PDFs with PDFReactor?

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I'm using PDFReactor 5 in Java to generate PDF files. The generated files must conform to the PDF/A1-a standard which does not allow transparency.

I use the PDFA conformance mode in PDFReactor like so `pdfReactor.setConformance(PDFreactor.CONFORMANCE_PDFA);` but the validator at http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx says my generated files are not valid PDF/A1-a since they contain transparency.

Any idea how one can configure PDFReactor to generate an opaque document?

Answer (score 1):

The way to generate is the one you used, so it's correct to set:

```
pdfReactor.setConformance(PDFreactor.CONFORMANCE_PDFA);
```

I have seen that `pdfreactor5` generates pdf not fully compatible with the pdf-a specs (transparency and others).

Upgrade to `pdfreactor6`.

After the upgrade my pdf was validated against http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx